# Height of background wont auto-adjust to the container

Tags: html, css

I want one section on my webpage with a fixed background and a gradient-overlay so the text is readable. The problem is that the background only covers the top 10 pixels or something like that. The height won't auto adjust to the size of the container. If i put in height: 200px etc it works but i would just like it to auto adjust to the content.

It shows like this with just the small bar of the background: [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g0ED.png)

HTML:

```
<section id="random" class="random">
<div class="content-wrap">


<div class="col-50-1">
<h2>Festivals</h2>
<p>
Donec in iaculis velit, eu viverra leo. Nullam eleifend, dolor at pharetra 
fringilla, eros est fermentum velit, rutrum vestibulum massa ligula ut 
purus. Mauris consectetur posuere ante, ullamcorper iaculis enim interdum 
vulputate. Duis finibus neque lectus. Nullam ligula libero, facilisis eget  
suscipit mi ullamcorper. Fusce ut sodales velit. Phasellus auctor ligula
</p>
</div>

<div class="col-50-2">
<h2>Uitgaan</h2>
<p>
Donec in iaculis velit, eu viverra leo. Nullam eleifend, dolor at pharetra 
fringilla, eros est fermentum velit, rutrum vestibulum massa ligula ut  
Fusce ut sodales velit. Phasellus auctor ligula est.
</p>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.random {
height:auto;
background: linear-gradient(rgba(141, 153, 174, 0.8), 
rgba(141, 153, 174, 0.5)),
url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/196652/pexels-photo-196652.jpeg) 
no-
repeat fixed;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided does work (see snippet). Based on the image, though I wonder if you've got some other code that possibly is interfering, specifically if you've got

```
.content-wrap {
  background: #fff;
}
```

I'd also play around with the `background-origin` and `background-position` declarations to be sure that the position of the image is correct with respect to the area that it's supposed to be behind.

```css
.random {
  height:auto;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(141, 153, 174, 0.8), rgba(141, 153, 174, 0.5)), url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/196652/pexels-photo-196652.jpeg) no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="random" id="random">
  <div class="content-wrap">
    <div class="col-50-1">
      <h2>Festivals</h2>
      <p>Donec in iaculis velit, eu viverra leo. Nullam eleifend, dolor at pharetra fringilla, eros est fermentum velit, rutrum vestibulum massa ligula ut purus. Mauris consectetur posuere ante, ullamcorper iaculis enim interdum vulputate. Duis finibus neque lectus. Nullam ligula libero, facilisis eget suscipit mi ullamcorper. Fusce ut sodales velit. Phasellus auctor ligula</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-50-2">
      <h2>Uitgaan</h2>
      <p>Donec in iaculis velit, eu viverra leo. Nullam eleifend, dolor at pharetra fringilla, eros est fermentum velit, rutrum vestibulum massa ligula ut Fusce ut sodales velit. Phasellus auctor ligula est.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```